# select starting digitals followed by first word in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I have lots of addresses in my database.
example: 1199 State Route 218

I want to select the starting digitals followed by first word and ignore the rest of the address.
so i want to retrieve address just by calling this: 1199 State

thanks for you help

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
regexp_substr(mycolumn, '^\\d+\\s+\\w+')
```

Regexp breakdown:

```
^    beginning of the string
\d+  a sequence of digits
\s+  a sequence of spaces
\w+  a sequence of word characters
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2e0fd56a687dfae7abe1c38ffb335fc)**:

```
select regexp_substr('1199 State Route 218', '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') v
```

```
| v          |
| :--------- |
| 1199 State |
```

---

On the other hand, if you are just looking to *filter* the table with the beginning of the adress, then `like` should be enough:

```
select address from listing where address like '1199 State %'
```

Note that the joker character (`%`) is preceeded by a space. This ensures that you are matching on the entire fist word rather than on part of it.

Comment: i am running 8.0 , is there anyway i want add a value instead of the column name to lets say: regexp_substr(1199 State, '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') and i get the full address 1199 State Route 218?

Comment: so lets say if i search for SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE regexp_substr('26480 Chapel.', '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') and i get the full address "26480 Chapel Ridge Rd"

Comment: @LearningPHPOOP: to *search* for the address, you don't really need a regex. See my updated answer.

Comment: the joker character did exactly want i wanted ..however first i have to extract the digitals followed  by a word against the provided value then i have to filter this down with the joker character ..

Comment: So: `like concat(regexp_substr('1199 State Route 218', '^\\d+\\s+\\w+'), ' %')`

Comment: If there is only one word in the address, the space before `%` will not work.  Suggest removing the space.

Comment: everything worked fine locally but when uploaded to the server i found out the on sever mysql is using the older version 5.7 , is there any way to convert this for 5.7 select regexp_substr('1199 State Route 218', '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') v – Learning PHP OOP 8 mins ago   Delete

Comment: @LearningPHPOOP: no, this is a MySQL 8.0 only solution (`regexp_substr()` is not available in earlier versions)... Side note: I don't know about a version 5.2 of MySQL (as far as concerned, it went from 5.1 to 5.5 without any version in between).

Comment: sorry it is 5.7 but it doesn't support regexp_substr() but it supports regexp

Comment: @GMB is there anyway to rewrite this for 5.7? i tried with regexp but didn't work was getting the full address

Comment: @GMB here is the solution that i came up with select SUBSTRING_INDEX(trim(street_address), ' ', 2) as street_address_extracted from user_listings and i see it working.